# 'Doubled' Image with a VGA to HDMI converter for the Dreamcast?

Tags: technical-issues, hdmi, sega-dreamcast

I have an issue connecting a game console (Dreamcast) to a VGA to HDMI converter and then to my TV. The converter works fine with the two laptops I have tested, but when trying the Dreamcast I get a weird image, sort of doubled (see picture).

Now, the converter allegedly supports a 640x480 @60Hz signal, which is what the Dreamcast is outputting.

Basically I'm asking whether the picture below offers any clues as to what might be going on. Is there some incompatibility between the console and the converter? Is the converter broken? Is the console broken?

[image: image of Dreamcast screen where everything is doubled]

Looking on the Internet, the voltage levels in the Dreamcast signal are apparently higher than in most consumer devices. I also found out that console signal uses SMPTE timing instead of the more common (?) VESA timing.

Could these factors be the culprit?

Comment: The timing might be the reason, Though I'd guess it's an interlaced signal issue and the converter is only designed for progressive inputs.

Comment: By the way, this is the wrong section to post this. Since this section is for the design of such circuits.

Comment: Unplug and replug all the cables and make sure they are connected right. Then Play with your tv settings to see. Dreamcast VGA to HDMI tends to work fine without issue most of the time, a quick google search has shown.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice this was the wrong section. Do I have to post it again in that section or will someone move it there? thanks.

By the way, the console is giving 480p, since it is a VGA signal.

Comment: To Passerby: I already did that and even opened the device and keep getting the same results. I would think the issue is in the converter, but then again, the laptops work fine, so I'm at a loss..

Comment: Have you tried the laptops at the same resolution/refresh as the console?

Comment: Unfortunately both laptops go down to 800x600 only. But I'll check with that tomorrow, thanks for the tip.